# aren't normals (read from NORMAL semantic ) in object space?

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, shader

when converting normals from object space to world space, the predefined matrix _Object2World works like a charm :(mul(_Object2World, normal)). both rotation and scaling (uniformly) gave the expected matrix through color checking elements in rows and columns, but why some code use normals to left multiply the inverse matrix _World2Object for object  space conversion,  is that a unity version thing (I'm using 4.5.2) or the normals do live in some other space other than object space, and why do the two matrices not respond to non-uniform scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aren't normals (read from NORMAL semantic ) in object space

Yes they are.

> the normals do live in some other space other than object space, and
>   why do the two matrices not respond to non-uniform scaling.

No the space is the same, but in a general case (not unity) a non [orthogonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) doesn't transform normals correctly.

If you want to perform a correct normal transformation in the general case you need to use the **inverse transpose** matrix. (In unity shaders this is equivalent to `mul(normal,_World2Object)`.

> _Object2World works like a charm :(mul(_Object2World, normal)). both rotation and scaling (uniformly) gave the expected matrix through
>   color checking elements in rows and columns

This is a bit tricky to explain (I hope to remember it correctly).
You can assume **scale is always uniform** because `Unity`(at least until 4.x version. I think it will change in 5.x) doesn't apply non-uniform scale in the vertex shader but pre-transform the mesh CPU side.

Following uniforms are provided to shaders:

- `_Object2World`: contains the world matrix including the scale
- `unity_Scale`: the w component contains the inverse of the uniform scale factor (`w = 1/scale`)
- `_World2Object`: contains the inverse world matrix without scale

In order to correctly transform the normal from object to world space, you have 3 possibility:

- **transform the scaled normal** : `float3 worldN = mul((float3x3)_Object2World, SCALED_NORMAL);`
- you can avoid to use the scaled normal if you **normalize** the normal after the transform (probably this is your case otherwise AFAIK the transformation shouldn't be 100% correct)
- **use the inverse transpose** : `mul(normal,_World2Object)`

`SCALED_NORMAL` is defined this way:

```
#define SCALED_NORMAL (v.normal * unity_Scale.w)
```